# what makes sending access token necessarily send using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' type?

Tags: http, access-token, rfc

I searched about this questions here and there, but couldn't find clear answer explain about my question.

By [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2), access_token can be send using body part of post message. I wonder why this docs give constraints set Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Is there any security reason client can't use `application/json` type when send post access token in body ?

Answer (score 1):

At least 99% of usage these days sends access tokens in the authorization header, as in section 2.1 of that doc. No-one does anything else.

Bear in mind that the doc is from 2012 and in those days certain clients, eg browsers or mobile browsers may have needed other options, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: Thank you sir. I wonder why docs noted to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which is not a application/json